# show percentage loading while fetching data with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to know if it is possible or if there are any plugins that can be used with Ajax in that while Data is being fetched in the background, it shows the percentage and it completes 100% after the data has finished loading.
Is that possible using jquery and also are there any plugins for that ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have one request or several? If you have only one request I don't think that javascript can solve this problem because your code is notified only when request is completed and response is received. So if you want to show percentage you should perform several requests. In that case you know how many chunks do you received and how many are remained.
However if you can show only progress bar without percentage you may do something like that:

```
function load(){
     showGifProgressBar();
     $.post(url, function(data){
         hideGifProgressBar();    
     });    
}
```

where showGifProgressBar will show any gif image([Loading gif examples](http://www.codeinsects.com/how-to-show-animated-loading-gif-image-in-internet-explorer-using-javascript.html))

Answer (score 0):

**It is not possible in JavaScript at all to get progress of ajax call**, there is no native functionality in the AJAX. There is not any plugin to do so.

> You can show [loading image](http://loadinggif.com/) when you start ajax call and hide the image when you will get response from server or your success function is called. The example code as follows:

```
showLoadingBar();
$.ajax({
  url:'/your/url',
  success:function(response){
      hideLoadingBar();
  }
})
```